# Discordjs list all guilds I am in

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is there any way to have a discord.js list all of the guilds that the bot is in (in console)? I have looked everywhere and cannot find a working solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) property.

```js
console.log(client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => guild.name).join('\n'))
```